# ToolTip only shows on "Click"- google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, tooltip, jquery-events

After several hours of searching for an answer I am unable to fix my problem.
I am working with latest jQuery and Google's API visualizations.

On page load, the `ColumnChart` renders properly. When you `mouseover` the bars it shows a hover-ish event being detected (highlighting of the edges - showing that `mouseover` is working). However, it doesn't show the tooltip box with the information.

Now when you click on the bar, the tooltip DOES appears. I never had this problem before. I thought the default for the hovering was to show the tool tip.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my .JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {

    
     $.post('presu.php', function ( data ) {    
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(data)); 
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                    view.setColumns([0, 
                                        {label: data.getColumnLabel(1),type: 'number', calc: function (dt, row) {
                                            return {v: dt.getValue(row, 1) / 1000000, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1)};
                                        }},
                                        {label: data.getColumnLabel(2),type: 'number', calc: function (dt, row) {
                                            return {v: dt.getValue(row, 2) / 1000000, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2)};
                                        }},
                                        {label: data.getColumnLabel(3),type: 'number', calc: function (dt, row) {
                                            return {v: dt.getValue(row, 3) / 1000000, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3)};
                                        } 
                    }]);
            
        var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('mdo'));
            columnChart.draw(view,
                     {title:"Cells",
                        width:600, 
                        height:400,
                        tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                        isStacked:true,
                        legend:'bottom',
                        tooltip:{},
                        focusTarget:"category"
                });
     });
    
})
```

Comment: I dont see any value that has been passed to your tooltip

Comment: The ColumnChart is render properly and when you click on the bar, the tooltip appears and displays the value correctly. Typically, this occurs by just hovering over. I am not so sure what do you mean by data passed to my tootip... according to google APIs documentation, tooltips are automatically generated from the source data.

Comment: I simply searched for tooltip in your code. now i see you have used google API visualization

Comment: i mean something like this `tooltip: {trigger : 'hover'}`

Comment: and why u have two `tooltip` defined?

Comment: I missed that I had already defined it once. I kept trying everything I could to fix it and that might have been a typo. I tried removing all options and just added tooltip: "{trigger : 'hover'}" and it still has the same behavior (Only shows tooltip on click)... thanks for your help

Comment: try it with the standard way: `var options = {
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    legend: 'none'
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('col_chart_html_tooltip'));
  chart.draw(dataTable, options);`

Comment: Still nothing... I have tried it all! Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, I get exactly the same behaviour. Even if I copy the demo code from the api site I do not get hover over tooltips, only when I click.

Comment: Ignore my comment above, this turned out to be a Chrome issue (ironically). When I tried in IE it worked fine. Restarting Chrome fixed my issue!